# Why parent method is called when child object is initialized and assigned to a parent object

Tags: c#, methods, overriding, parent

I want to declare a parent variable, then assign it with a child object
when the parent variable calls a method (exists in both parent / child), it should use the child's version.

```
public abstract class TowInt
{
    public int One;
    public int Two;
    public char Operator;
    public int Result;
    public int Remainder;

    public void init()
    {
        calc();
    }

    protected abstract void calc();

    public string getAnswer()
    {
        return Convert.ToString(Result);
    }
    public string getQuestion()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1} {2} = ", One, Operator, Two);
    }
}

public class TwoIntPlus : TowInt
{

    public TwoIntPlus(int one, int two)
    {
        One = one;
        Two = two;
        Operator = '+';
    }
    protected override void calc()
    {
        Result = One + Two;
    }
}

public class TwoIntDivision : TowInt
{
    public TwoIntDivision(int one, int two)
    {
        One = one;
        Two = two;
        Operator = '/';
    }
    protected override void calc()
    {
        Result = One / Two;
        Remainder = One % Two;
    }

    new public virtual string getAnswer()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}R{1}", Result, Remainder);
    }
}



using System.IO;

class ConsoleApplication1
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // For child class, the child method getAnswer() is called
        TwoIntDivision n2 = new TwoIntDivision(32, 4);
        n2.init();
        Console.WriteLine(n2.getQuestion() + n2.getAnswer());
        // 32 / 4 = 8R0  -- this is what I expected

        // If assign a child object to parent, then the parent method is called
        TowInt two;
        two = new TwoIntDivision(32, 4);
        two.init();
        Console.WriteLine(two.getQuestion() + two.getAnswer());
        // 32 /4 = 8 -- this is not what I expected

        two = new TwoIntPlus(32, 4);
        two.init();
        Console.WriteLine(two.getQuestion() + two.getAnswer());



        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please only post the *relevant* code to the problem you are having.

Comment: TL;DR - try to focus on what code is relevant to your question. And state clearly what your question actually is..

Comment: Also, C# is not java. Use properties instead of get/set methods.

Comment: Why do you not expect 32/4 = 8 when you instantiate the division object? That seems like the right behavior to me... If its just the format, you didn't mark it as `virtual` in the base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you have not marked the `getAnswer` method as virtual in the base class.

So, in the `TwoIntDivision` class you are hiding - not overriding (extending) the base class method:

```
// this is hiding the base class method, not overriding it (notice the new modifier)
new public virtual string getAnswer()
```

Then, when you cast your object, depending on the type it will use the method for the type you are working with. This is totally expected behavior and can come in handy in the right context.

To get the behavior you expect, modify your definitions like this:

```
public abstract class TowInt
{    
   public virtual string getAnswer() {
       return "Hello from Base-Class";
  }    
}

public class TwoIntDivision : TowInt
{
   public override string getAnswer() {
        return "Hello from Division";
   }
}

TowInt t = new TwoIntDivision();
Console.WriteLine(t.getAnswer());     // prints "Hello from Division"
```

As a side note, in case you are coming from a Java background, in C# methods are final (non-virtual) by default. If you want to allow a method to be overrideable in a derived class you have to explicitly mark it with the `virtual` modifier.

Comment: Didn't even notice he had the `new` to hide, though I noticed the virtual in the wrong place. Nice catch!

Comment: Some other things that indicate a Java background include `camelCase` method names rather than `PascalCase` method names, and putting opening braces on the same line as the method name, the first of which you've left alone in your answer, the second of which you've specifically applied in your answer.

Comment: The reason not using virtual in parent method is that I don't want every child class to override the function (the getAnswer() is the same for +-* except /).  I just want the TwoIntDivision to override it.  Is there another way to accomplish this without override it in every child class?

Comment: Classes that extend your base class, are not required to override a method marked `virtual`. The only methods that *must* but overriden are methods marked `abstract` (and those only by the initial class the extends the abstract class). The `virtual` modifier simply indicates to the CLR that the method *may be* overriden by a more specilized class.